# Unable to define table relationship to be used with Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

Apologize for duplication as I believe I did not ask question property (Reposting question)

I have two models Movie and Category

-The Movie class has a PK

public Int64 **MovieSer** { get; set; }  //PK

-and includes the list of categories property

public List Categories { get; set; }

The category class as a primary and foreign key

public Int64 CategorySer { get; set; }  //PK

public Int64 **MovieSer** { get; set; }  //FK

I am trying to use OnModelCreating() method to define relationship as follows:

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

{

//this partially works, if mapped to CategoryId -Not what I want though

// modelBuilder.Entity().HasMany(o =>

o.Categories).WithOne().HasForeignKey(s=>s.CategoryId);

**//what I want is to map it MovieSer** but add-migration fails

modelBuilder.Entity().HasMany(o =>

o.Categories).WithOne().HasForeignKey(s=>s.**MovieSer**);

}

BUT Add-Migration fails
ERROR:
The relationship from 'Category' to 'Movie.Categories' with foreign key properties {'MoviesSer' : long} cannot target the primary key {'MovieSer' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, by adding a HasPrincipalKey(e=>e.MovieSer)
worked.